# Extreme points of the unit ball of bounded operators on $L^p(\mathbb{R}_+)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

Is it known what the set of all extreme points of $B(L^p(\mathbb{R}_+))$ (bounded operators on $L^p(\mathbb{R}_+)$) is?

Comment: The paper R. Grząślewicz, Extreme operators on 2-dimensional $\ell_p$-spaces. 
Colloq. Math. 44, 309-315 (1981), Zbl 0475.47028, appears to be the first attempt at this problem. I don't know about higher dimensions, let alone $L_p(\mathbb R_+)$.